# get error label to line up with input in flex-wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In the example below, I would like to bring the validation message vertically inline with the input so the bullet point is roughly inline with the left hand side of the input without using explicit widths.

```css
.form-control__input {
  display: flex
}

.form-control__input.form-control__vertical {
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start
}

.form-control__input.form-control__horizontal {
  flex: 1 1;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center
}

.form-control__input.form-control__horizontal .form-control__wrapper {
  flex: 1 1
}

.form-control__input.form-control__horizontal [role=alert] {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="form-control__input form-control__horizontal"><label for="ctrl5" id="ctrl5-label" class="label__default">Horizontal</label>
  <div class="form-control__wrapper"><input autocomplete="off" class="input__default form-control input__invalid" id="ctrl5" aria-invalid="true" aria-describedby="ctrl5-error" maxlength="100" type="text"></div>
  <div id="ctrl5-error" aria-hidden="false" role="alert">
    <ul class="current-errors error-label__container">
      <li data-selector="form-error">foo bar</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `display: grid` instead of `display: flex` in this case so you can line up the element like table.

You can give the area name to each `div` and position each area in parent's `grid-template-area` property

```css
.form-control__input.form-control__vertical {
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start
}

.form-control__input .label_default {
      grid-area: label;
}

.form-control__input.form-control__horizontal {
  display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "label input" ". error";
    grid-template-columns: min-content;
}

.form-control__input.form-control__horizontal .form-control__wrapper {
  grid-area: input;
}

.form-control__input.form-control__horizontal [role=alert] {
  grid-area: error;
}

.form-control__input.form-control__horizontal [role=alert]  ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-control__input form-control__horizontal"><label for="ctrl5" id="ctrl5-label" class="label__default">Horizontal</label>
  <div class="form-control__wrapper"><input autocomplete="off" class="input__default form-control input__invalid" id="ctrl5" aria-invalid="true" aria-describedby="ctrl5-error" maxlength="100" type="text"></div>
  <div id="ctrl5-error" aria-hidden="false" role="alert">
    <ul class="current-errors error-label__container">
      <li data-selector="form-error">foo bar</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this would be to replace the `flex-wrap: wrap` with `flex-wrap: nowrap`.
In case you wanted to keep the `flex-wrap` to `wrap` (I could not ask in the comments) you could make a seperate `div` with the items which should be `wrapped`.